# Why "Properties that return arrays are prone to code inefficiencies"?

Tags: oop, performance, fxcop

I have a piece of code which deals with customers stored in database. There is an object `Customer`, and it has, among other, two properties of type `byte[]`: one property for password salt, the second one for password hash.

Checking the code with FxCop, I see that it complains (*CA1819*, *Performance Rules*) that:

> "Properties that return arrays are prone to code inefficiencies. Consider using a collection or making this a method. See the design guidelines for more information."

and suggests:

> "Change 'Customer.PasswordHash' to return a collection or make it a method."

I don't really understand, what is the code inefficiency in what I'm doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that arrays are *always* mutable. That means you can't return one from a method without either:

- Allowing the caller to mess up your internal state
- Creating a copy first

If you use a collection, you can create a read only wrapper around the real collection instead, and return that - and that can be considerably cheaper. Alternatively, if you change it to a method that will lower the expectation that it will be very quick to call.

Of course, if you're happy with callers mutating your data, then an array will work fine...