# CA1819: Properties should not return arrays. Does this rule apply for other objects too?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, msdn

Regarding the CA1819 msdn performance warning rule:

> Arrays returned by properties are not write-protected, even if the
>   property is read-only. To keep the array tamper-proof, the property
>   must return a copy of the array. Typically, users will not understand
>   the adverse performance implications of calling such a property.
>   Specifically, they might use the property as an indexed property.

I want to know if other objects are mutable when returned by the property, or if this only happens for arrays?  If it is only valid for arrays, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA1819: Properties shouldn't return arrays - What is the right alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820992/ca1819-properties-shouldnt-return-arrays-what-is-the-right-alternative)

Answer (score 3):

Let say you have:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

public int[] Ints { get { return ints; } }
```

The consumer of your class can do:

```
instance.Ints[0] = 10;
```

So you're allowing modification of the data of the class.

To prevent this you can done something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Ints { get { return ints; } }
```

So the consumer of your class can only read the values but not modify.

Now, why?

Well it depends on the design of your class if you want let modify the data of array, the warning warns you about the fact that maybe you expect that the values of the array cannot be manipulated because you don't have a `set` in the property.

PS: there a lot of methods, like readonly collection etc..., to prevent altering your collections

Take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this using object (string) and it does not allow me to modify the value of the string , i want to know if any other object is mutable like arrays(does this happen with any other object type)? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to know if this happens with other objects type too, (i tried doing this with strings and it doesn't allow modification), are there any other object that are mutable, except arrays? Thanks again.

Comment: The object itself is not mutable, you can change it's data, the problem arises with collection in generals, like `List<T>` etc.

Comment: Can we say that the only mutable objects in this situation are arrays  and this does not happen with other types of objects like List<T> etc. For example i have  private IDbCommand idbCommand;  and property: public IDbCommand Command     
    {
      get
      {
        return idbCommand;
      }
    }   is idbCommand mutable???      Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you tell me why this only happens with arrays?

Comment: I understand that i can return a read only type, the thing i want to know is the reason why arrays are mutable and other objects are not when returned from a property that does not have a setter method.Thank you for your time.

Comment: Read the article of the link.

Comment: What about the cases that when the client is changing the array it is still perfectly valid, why do they distinctively make this guideline for all cases??